# Was ist "Meschores" und von welcher Etymologie ist dieses Wort?

Tags: meaning, etymology

In "Der Golem" von Gustav Meyrink:

> aber  der ›**Meschores**‹ - der  Gemeindediener  - war  infolge göttlicher
>   Erleuchtung noch rechtzeitig draufgekommen und konnte die beiden Verbrecher der
>   Stadtpolizei überliefern.

Es gibt kein "Meschores" in [Duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/meschores), [Langenscheidt](https://en.langenscheidt.com/german-english/search?term=meschores&q_cat=%2F%2F) und [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/), die ich normalerweise nutze.

Wenn ich google, finde ich auch kein Antwort gerade.

Ich denke, dass die Etymologie ist Jiddisch, weil die Ereignisse sich in der judischen Stadtteil Prags finden.

Comment: Auch im jiddischen Wörterbuch auf Anhieb nichts gefunden. Evtl. ugs. Verballhornung von lat. *mesochorus*, Chorführer?

Comment: @Philipp ich hab was eigentlich selbst gefuden. Siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: Super, darauf wäre ich nicht gekommen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich habe etwas selbst gefunden.

[Wörterbuch](http://de.slovopedia.com/119/77/1351480.html) der deutschen Umgangssprache:

> Meschores  Me'schores m \
>
> 1. Diener, Knecht. Aus dem Jidd seit 1750.  \
> 2. unzuverlässiger Mann. 1900 ff.

[Wörterbuch](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=0SIhAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=meschores%20worterbuch&source=bl&ots=J11fXprjlF&sig=ACfU3U0ydBJKgCYee52NwFp27RE47FzY4Q&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjU8_G2oInhAhVphosKHSw_BgcQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=meschores%20worterbuch&f=false) zum jiddischen Lehnwortschatz in den deutschen Dialekten:

[image]

Also, das Wort "Meschores" stammt aus Jiddisch, wo es aus dem hebräischen

> [לשרת](https://www.morfix.co.il/%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%AA) - dienen

stammt.

Comment: (updated links). Anyhow your quoted word starts with the letter Lamet, no *m* in sight. I'm no expert either, by any means.

Comment: I messed up the links. Here it goes again. Arab. *sharif* https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sharif Hebr. *sheret* https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA#Hebrew Also see *shira* https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94#Hebrew perhaps

Comment: *-t* is may be an abstractum or female gender suffix, originally (I mean it sometimes is). Indeed, we find שִׁיר (shir) "song, poem". Also שַׂר (sár) "officer, commander; prince; guardian angel". cp. "der Schah"? The connection here may be *temple servant*, *Messdiener*.

Comment: @vectory לשרת starts with 'lamed,' as it is the infinitive form. It becomes 'mesharet' in 'ani mesharet' or 'אני משרת' or 'I serve,' for example.

Comment: @vectory I mean, "sh+r" and "sh+r+t" are two different roots. It could be a female suffix, yes, but it isn't here. Here "tav" letter is one of the root letters.

Comment: Why would you say that? The semantic parallel via "commander" and the like is convincing to me. We see "[shereef](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shereef#English) (historical) A member of an Arab princely family descended from Muhammad ..." so some chiefly biased folk etymology should be expected in Muslim sources at least. Also, Arabic etymology is overall focused on getting the stem roots right just to support learning the vowel alternation around the stems. But that has little to do with reconstruction efforts. Although, I do not doubt the root may have become independent at some point.

Answer (score 5):

Im Hessischen wird Meschores noch häufiger benutzt. Hier ein Auszug aus einem Artikel [Hessisch für Anfänger](https://www.fnp.de/kolumnen/hessisch-anfaenger-10743189.html) der Frankfurter Neuen Presse:

> Einfalt und Willfährigkeit verbindet man auch mit dem Ausdruck „einem de Maschores mache“. Im Jiddischen bezeichnet „meschores“ den Knecht oder Diener. In den hessischen Mundarten reicht die Bedeutungsvielfalt von der dienstbeflissenen Arbeitskraft, einem einfältigen Menschen bis zum Possenreißer.
>
> „Den Maschores spielen“ sagt man von einem, der überall und am besten vorne mit dabei sein will. Der „Owwermaschores“ kann der Ortsvorsteher, Vereinsvorsitzende, Oberkellner oder der Chef von irgendwas sein und soll verdeutlichen, dass sich hier die Beziehung Herr – Diener ins Gegenteil verkehrt hat.

Comment: danke schön! sehr interessant! was ist "am besten vorne mit dabei sein"? das verstehe ich nicht.

Comment: @P.Vowk: Ich kenne den Begriff nur passiv als Wichtigtuerei im Vereins- oder lokalpolitischen Kontext. Indem ich mich beispielsweise als Kassenwart bei einem Verein wählen lasse, kann ich mich in einer sozial wichtigen Position wähnen - allerdings sind die meisten Mitglieder schlicht und einfach froh irgendeinen Idioten gefunden zu haben, der diese undankbare Aufgabe übernimmt.

Comment: Ich Frage mich ob es nicht von einer Verwechslung mit lat. *Major* beeinflusst wurde.